# Unusual for a US Secret Service official to also be "a political adviser at the White House"? (Washington Post)

Tags: united-states, political-appointments, secret-service

The Washington Post's April 23, 2022 [Meadows was warned of violence ahead of Jan. 6, new court filings show](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2022/04/23/meadows-jan6-secret-service-committee-testimony/) includes:

> One of Meadows’s top aides, Cassidy Hutchinson, told congressional investigators that she recalled **Anthony Ornato, a senior Secret Service official who also held the role of a political adviser at the White House**, “coming in and saying that we had intel reports saying that there could potentially be violence on the 6th. And Mr. Meadows said: All right. Let’s talk about it.”

Somehow "a senior Secret Service official who also held the role of a political adviser" seems strange to me; for example Wikipedia's [United States Secret Service; Primary missions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Secret_Service#Primary_missions) lists Protective and Investigative missions (and there are several things they investigate besides protective issues) but nothing about providing *political advice*.

So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Is it unusual for a US Secret Service official to serve as "a *political adviser* at the White House" as the Washington Post article seems to suggest?

Comment: there are no secret-service, federal-agency or other tags that seem to apply, but I welcome suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure he did this simultaneously? His [official government biography](https://www.fleta.gov/profile/anthony-m-ornato) doesn't give dates but suggests that he's held a series of positions rather than holding all at once.

Comment: Concerning tags, [White House Deputy Chief of Staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Deputy_Chief_of_Staff). "The deputy chief of staff usually has an office in the West Wing and is responsible for ensuring the smooth running of the White House bureaucracy, ..." also "Tony Ornato, 2019–2021". The tags [tag:bureaucracy] and [tag:public-administration] relate to the position, generally; but [tag:president] covers the "office of President" centered in the White House. I suggest [tag:president] since "political adviser at the White House" is, perhaps indirectly, adviser to the president.

Comment: @StuartF from time to time my brain mis-parses sentences. I was certain the sentence indicates that they were at the same time, but re-reading it seems there's no such requirement. I suppose "...who *had* also held the role..." might have better way to write it, but probably most people (besides me) would read it as them being different jobs at different times. So perhaps there is no profound question here. You're welcome to add a short answer to that effect and I can call it "problem solved". Otherwise if there's no further action I may just delete it.

Comment: @RickSmith please feel free to add tags accordingly, thanks!

Comment: I don't see where the quote from *WaPo* suggests it's *unusual*. I'm not certain the [tag:fact-check-request] applies for that quote. [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/dec/31/joe-biden-secret-service-team-trump-loyalty) noted "In what was described as an 'unprecedented' move, [temporary leave for Ornato]"; but the source for "unprecedented" was not given. Changing the quote from *WaPo* to *The Guardian* could be a [tag:fact-check-request] on "unprecedented"; but then some might suggest migration to Skeptics SE.

Comment: This is about [tag:political-appointments] of [tag:civil-service] employees in the [tag:united-states]. I am considering creating a [secret-service] tag; however, *secret service* describes different organizations in different countries, If the tag is created, it will affect possibly [23 questions.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22secret+service%22+is%3Aq) and will require a non-US centric excerpt.

Comment: @RickSmith a tag about safety, security, and protection of politicians would be inherently international. I think that a tag named after the US Secret Service itself would not fly because that's a strictly non-political entity.

Comment: "I think that a tag named after the US Secret Service itself would not fly because that's a strictly non-political entity": that's no reason not to have a have a tag for it.  It is nonetheless an entity that may be the object of political debates or the subject of political scandals (the potential for which is probably, I suppose, your reason for asking this question).

Comment: [Proposal for two tags: intelligence-service and secret-service](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6249/16047)